# Service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - xp0.xconnect-IndexWorker Cannot start service xp0.xconnect-IndexWorker on computer '

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework

am facing the issues while installing Sitecore 9, and getting below errors

I have a valid licence and **solr is up and running and version is 6.2.2**

```
[---------------------------------------------------------- StartServices [1] : ManageService --------------------------------------------------------------]
[StartServices [1]]:[Updating] xp0.xconnect-IndexWorker
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - xp0.xconnect-IndexWorker (xp0.xconnect-IndexWorker)' **cannot be started due to 
the following error: Cannot start service xp0.xconnect-IndexWorker on computer '.'.**
At C:\Users\sitecoretr\Downloads\OneDrive_2018-07-02\sitecore 9\SIFLess\SIFless-EZ-1530793277.ps1:42 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:03:35
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\Windows\system32\xconnect-xp0.180705 (20).log
Start-Service : Service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - xp0.xconnect-IndexWorker (xp0.xconnect-IndexWorker)' cannot be started due to the following 
error: Cannot start service xp0.xconnect-IndexWorker on computer '.'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Tasks\Invoke-ManageServiceTask.ps1:40 char:33
+                     $instance | Start-Service
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

The below error in the event viewer

```
The Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - xp0.xconnect-IndexWorker service failed to start due to the following error: 
Access is denied
```

Comment: What's the user account that the service is running as?

Comment: You have the xconnect index worked in Windows Services. Can you find it (it's name start with Sitecore) right click and run

Comment: the user account is **NT AUTHORITY\\LocalService**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add "Everyone" role and give full rights in WWW (rootfolder) XConnect Site.[image]

Comment: It should be sufficient to grant permissions to \xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\ folder.

Comment: And only the user running the service.. not everyone.